# How to generate a random vector, guaranteed to be within the hemisphere with respect to another vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, spherical-geometry

Given a normalized vector `N`, how can one generate a random direction vector that is guaranteed to be in the hemisphere with respect to `N` (i.e. the hemisphere where `N` is exactly in the middle)? The way I am currently doing this is to sample a random direction vector `d` and `dot` it with `N` and keep that vector if the `dot` product is greater than `0`. This method is not guaranteed to generate a vector in the hemisphere that I am interested in as ~50% of the random vectors would have a `0` or negative `dot` product result.

I saw somewhere that there is a way to transform the randomly generated vector `d` to place it in the right hemisphere using a transformation matrix but I don't know how to do it. Can someone write a [pseudo]code for how one generate a direction vector using the transformation method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you can just randomly generate $d$, and if it does not lie in the right hemisphere, because $d \cdot N < 0$, replace $d$ by $-d$.

Comment: Thanks. I think that's a super simply and effective way of doing what I explained. However, what if the goal is to generate random direction vectors that are within `θ` degrees of the `Normal`?

Comment: That's harder. I think rejection sampling (trying over and over again until you get a good direction) is the easiest way to do it, and if $\theta$ is not too small, it will work reasonably well. If $\theta \le 90^\circ$, then we can combine that with the idea in my answer: try $d$, if that doesn't work try $-d$, and if that doesn't work start over. This will speed things up by a factor of $2$.

Comment: The fancier way would be to represent vectors in spherical coordinates with $N$ at one pole, and randomly generate the two angles, but non-uniformly. I'd have to think about what the distribution should be.

Comment: Thanks, that would be great

Answer (score 3):

To answer your followup question from the comments: If you're in 3D, we have the convenient fact that the $z$ coordinate of a random point on the unit sphere is uniformly distributed. So if you take $z\sim U(\cos\theta,1)$, $\phi\sim U(0,2\pi)$, $r=\sqrt{1-z^2}$, then $\left(r\cos\phi,r\sin\phi, z\right)$ is a random point on the sphere within $\theta$ radians of the positive $z$-axis.

To transform this to be within $\theta$ radians of $N$, multiply it by an orthonormal matrix whose last column is $N$. (In other words, apply the transformation $(x,y,z)\mapsto(xV,yW,zN)$ where $V$ and $W$ are unit vectors that are orthogonal to $N$ and to each other.)